# How to reshape a wide dataframe (many columns, fewer rows) as a long one (few columns, many rows)?

Tags: pandas

I want to transform a dataset consisting of 189 rows from this:

**(base)**

[image]

to this:
**(desired result)**

[image]

My idea was to use `df.groupby('country').T`

Which I think leads into the correct direction:

[image]

But it is not the intended result.

I want the first row to be a column – like in the first image above.

So I tried `df['country'] = df.iloc[0]` leading just to the same result as above (last image)

despite of the different column names which I know how to handle I want the base dataframe to be like the result frame. Is it actually an transposing issue – or something else?
The desired columns are just: 'country', 'year' and 'hdi'

Comment: Try to apply `.stack()` method of DataFrame to the last df you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["Afghanistan", "Angola"],
        1990: [0.302, 0.405],
        1991: [0.307, 0.412],
        1992: [0.316, 0.419],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
       country   1990   1991   1992
0  Afghanistan  0.302  0.307  0.316
1       Angola  0.405  0.412  0.419
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```py
df = (
    df
    .groupby("country")
    .agg(list)
    .applymap(lambda x: x[0])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "year", 0: "hdi"})
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
       country  year    hdi
0  Afghanistan  1990  0.302
1  Afghanistan  1991  0.307
2  Afghanistan  1992  0.316
3       Angola  1990  0.405
4       Angola  1991  0.412
5       Angola  1992  0.419
```